# Parallax scrolling with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have been working on a project and I am done with the content. For the design however, I am thinking of using the parallax scrolling technique.

However, all I have been able to find out about it has been with JavaScript or Jquery, whereas I am only proficient with CSS3.

Can parallax scrolling be implemented with CSS3 only(with HTML5 if needed), instead of using jquery plugins? It would be nice if I could be pointed to some tutorials for the same.

Note: This is close to the effect I want to produce(http://jessandruss.us/)

Comment: I don't think it's possible using only CSS. You'll have to detect scrolling (and the currently viewed element) in order to achieve this effect (CSS afaik doesn't support detecting position from a scrolled page). Also some images scroll to certain point and then they "stop" when certain scroll occurs. This only gives you an option for some type of scripting detecting these cases, and CSS won't give that to you. Javascript is intended for processing, CSS is only for displaying elements and some basic interactions (like hovers). Also, that link you provided actually used jQuery for achieving that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I really like [KitKat’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23280573/877703), but as Roy Prins suggested, it would be very helpful to reduce it down to the bare essentials, to see precisely what is sufficient to create this effect. I’ve done so here.

**To produce a very basic parallax scroll effect, the following example is sufficient.** Note that browser prefixes, fallbacks, etc. have not been addressed. CSS values marked with `/* e.g. */` may be changed at the designer’s discretion.

See my [forked pen here](http://codepen.io/chharvey/full/aNVELy/).

```
<html><head><style>
  html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  body {
    perspective: 1px; /* e.g. */
  }
  .background {
    transform:
      translateZ(-.4px)
      scale(.6)
      translateX(-104%)
      translateY(-40%)
      rotate(-5deg); /* e.g. */
  }
  .foreground {
    transform:
      translateZ(.25px)
      translateX(50%)
      scale(.75)
      rotate(2deg); /* e.g. */
  }
</style></head><body>
  <img class="background"/>
  <img class="foreground"/>
</body></html>
```

A minor correction to KitKat’s answer:
It seems that one doesn’t need `transform-style:preserve-3d` (at least in Chrome), and that the effect rather **depends on the body’s `overflow:auto`**. Remove this and the parallax fails.

Comment: It was an old question, but I will accept your answer as it was the closest to being accurate, even if not the first.

Answer (score 17):

Searching for [parallax pure css](http://www.google.com/search?q=parallax%20pure%20css) and clicking on the [first result from CodePen](http://codepen.io/keithclark/full/JycFw) (the second result is the current page :), a nice example is displayed with both **fixed** and **scrolling** backgrounds. For the record, I place the source code here, providing support for Chrome, Safari and Opera, too.

The example appears to have two kinds of backgrounds:

- **fixed**, with `background-attachment: fixed` in the desired element, like `#slide2`
- **scrolling**, with `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2)` *before* the desired element, like `#slide1`

Moreover, the scrolling effect seems to depend on the setting `transform-style: preserve-3d` of `body` to work properly. (IE doesn't happen to [support `transform-style`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-style.asp), by the way.)

Finally, different scrolling speeds can be achieved by tweaking `transform` property, like the two `img` elements of the example.

[**Source code**](http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title> Pure CSS Parallax Scrolling </title>
    <!-- Copyright (c) 2014 by Keith Clark -->
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
        html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body { 
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            perspective: 1px;
            -webkit-perspective: 1px;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            font-family: Nunito;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 250%
        }
        p {
            font-size: 140%;
            line-height: 150%;
            color: #333;
        }
        .slide {
            position: relative;
            padding: 25vh 10%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
            -webkit-transform-style: inherit;
            transform-style: inherit;
        }
        img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 35%;
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
            transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
        }
        img:last-of-type {
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
            transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
        }
        .slide:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
        }
        .title {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 5%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
        }
        .slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        .slide, .slide:before {
            background: 50% 50% / cover;  
        }
        .header {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 175%;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
        }
        #title {
            background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;  
        }
        #slide1:before {
            background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-4.jpg");
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
            transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
            z-index:-1;
        }
        #slide2 {
            background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-3.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #slide3:before {
            background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg");
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
            transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
            z-index:-1;
        }
        #slide4 {
            background: #222;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title" class="slide header">
        <h1>Pure CSS Parallax</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-4.jpg"> 
    </div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide4" class="slide header">
        <h1>The End</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This source code example would have really benefited from reduction to the bare essentials.

Comment: This example is hard to implement in existing pages. Note that the `<html>`-container does not scroll here, but the body. Also all elements up to the actual slide have to have `height: 100%` set.

Comment: @RoyPrins I'm working on that now, check back for my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to get at least a partial effect by using CSS transitions. However, as Alejandro mentioned, CSS doesn't detect scroll.

Take a look at "That Cool Parallax Scrolling Effect - in Pure CSS3!" (http://css.dzone.com/articles/cool-parallax-scrolling-effect) for an example.

The key is using internal page links. So instead of scrolling, a user would click an in-page link and the page would then scroll up/down to the new section. As the page scrolls, the transitions provide the parallax effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 500px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anandchakru/full/XVqYwa/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you want a simple basic parallax effect then CSS3 **@keyframes rule** would be sufficient(not so parallax) but again like the others mentioned if you want to use parallax to the fullest then using javascript is a must. I have anyways given you links for both the ways. Feel free to check them both and use what you want

Pure CSS3 :

http://jasonlau.biz/home/css/parallax-effect-using-only-css-with-no-javascript /* with keyframes */

http://css.dzone.com/articles/cool-parallax-scrolling-effect /* without keyframes */

With JQuery:

http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-effect/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-scrolling-parallax-website/

Hope it helped

Comment: its not jquery that is a must, but javascript. skrollr for example is a relatively easy library for parallax scrolling (and more) that does not use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

[DNA Parallax / CSS Keyframes Parallax Animator](https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/dna-parallax)

This parallax uses standard CSS animation (using @keyframes at-rule) to define scrolling effects. You don't need any javascript knowledge.

The only need is to include 2 configuration-less javascript files (jquery + DNA Parallax CSS plugin) that will automatically run @keyframes animation on the element as you scroll...